# Unable to insert "BIT" value in MySQL using Nifi PutDatabaseRecord due to Data truncation error

Tags: mysql, json, apache-nifi, bit

I am trying to create a mirror DB for Mysql using CaptureChangeMysql. While trying to replicate a table with the "BIT" date type column, I am getting the error due to data truncation. The data type for the column status is "BIT" which is inserted in the source database with correct value is attached. JSON generated for the insert operation through CaptureChangeMysql also attached. During the insert operation in the destination table through PutDatabaseRecord, getting an error. PFA. Please suggest a solution to fix the issue.[image: InputJson][image: Source table data][image: Error]

Comment: Any suggestions or links to convert bit value in JSON.

Comment: I am using the expression below, but did not get the expected output.
${ status:equals("[{0}]"):ifElse("TRUE","FALSE") }

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question, It should be ${field.value:equals({0}"):ifElse("TRUE","FALSE")} in "UpdateRecord" processor.